# Django string filter and output dictionary index value

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to filter out the parts of a domain to use in my Django template.  I want to reference multiple parts of the returned dictionary.

For example:

```
{% for item in data %}
    {{ item.url|parse_domain }}
{% endfor %}
```

My parse_domain filter returns the subdomain, the host, and the .com/net/org, but what I'd like to do is reference any index of the returned value at the same time.  Is that possible within the template?

Like:

```
{{ item.url|parse_domain|0 }} = "subdomain"
```

Or would I have to loop over it again, giving me nested for loops?

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `slice` filter to index the returned dictionary.